# Azure Emulator - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: azure, emulation

All.
I've got Azure SDK 1.7 installed. 
All the assemblies in the solution are compiled with 'Any CPU' set up. But one of them fails when i start the solution in Azure emulator on my machine.
The error is very strange: "Could not load file or assembly 'XXX' or one of its dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application."

It becomes more complicated to find the reason, cause on the other machine everything works fine. Also I have no error when deploy it to Azure environment.

Tried to start emulator using IIS Express 8 and full IIS. Also tried to enable 32bit apps support when hosted under full IIS. Converted project to use 1.8 SDK.

But with no success.

Here is also some info from Visual Studio General output. Seems, here is the reason for the issue.

```
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete file fr000001.xml.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete file fr000002.xml.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete file fr000001.xml.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete file fr000002.xml.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete file fr000001.xml.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete file fr000002.xml.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete file fr000001.xml.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete file fr000002.xml.
Windows Azure Tools: Warning: Unable to delete directory deployment17(397)
```

Couldn't find the process that can create such behavior. Of course, tried to restart my machine and to remove all the readonly properties from project files.

Will be glad to see any possible solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've found the source of problem.
When installed RedGate .NET Reflector, it created environment variable with name DEVPATH.
It's value is: "C:\ProgramData\Red Gate.NET Reflector\DevPath"

I've looked through this path and found there obsolete dll for my project. As result, it searched for the reference as it performs with GAC and always found incorrect one.

Removed and everything works.